# Converting std::wstring to SQLWCHAR *

Tags: c++, sql, odbc, wstring

I have a C++ program that is dynamically creating a query string which will then be passed to a `SQLExecDirect` call to connect to a database using ODBC. I'm having trouble passing the variable from one function to another, so I think I must be missing something basic?

In the `ConstructQuery` function (which returns type `SQLWCHAR *`), I have:

```
std::wstring test = L"test string"; //This test string will actually be several concatenated strings
SQLWCHAR *statement = (SQLWCHAR *)test.c_str();
std::wcout << statement;
return statement;
```

This prints the statement variable as expected. But when I pass the variable to my main function like this:

```
SQLStatement = ConstructQuery(SQLStatement);
std::wcout << SQLStatement;
```

I get no output.

If, instead of `statement = (SQLWCHAR *)test.c_str()`;

I use: `statement = L"test string"`;

The variable passes fine, but then I am not able to dynamically create the "test string" query in the earlier part of the function.

I was having a hard time finding out much about `SQLWCHAR`. I'm guessing that I may be converting `std::wstring` to `SQLWCHAR *` incorrectly? Another option would be to rewrite the function so that all of the `wstring` are `SQLWCHAR *` and do the concatenation that way - but I'm not sure that's possible and even if it was I don't think it's preferred?

Comment: I knew it was something basic, thanks very much. Is there a way that I can accept your comment as the answer for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning a pointer to a local variable that goes out of scope at the end of the function ConstructQuery. It might be easiest to return a `std::wstring` by value and then work from there.