# How to convert from std::string to SQLWCHAR*

Tags: c++

I'm trying to convert `std::string` to `SQLWCHAR*`, but I couldn't find how.

Any brilliant suggestion, please?

Comment: Refer to the following post: [Post][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11275225/converting-stdwstring-to-sqlwchar

Comment: @user3037661, that's `std::wstring`

Comment: Shoot good catch, never mind then

Comment: What you need to do is to convert your multi-byte string to a wide-char string. This depends on how your std::string is encoded (e.g UTF8?). Windows has a useful function called `MultiByteToWideChar`. Other platforms (or string libraries) will have equivalent functions.

Comment: @pbergqvist, I'm using Unicode Character set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to simply use a std::wstring in the first place, rather than std::string. With Unicode Character set you can define a wide string literal using the following syntax:

```
std::wstring wstr = L"hello world";
```

However, if you would like to stick with std::string then you will need to convert the string to a different encoding. This will depend on how your std::string is encoded. The default encoding in Windows is ANSI (however the most common encoding when reading files or downloading text from websites is usually UTF8).

This answer shows a function for converting a std::string to a std::wstring on Windows (using the `MultiByteToWideChar` function).

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27296/966782

Note that the answer uses `CP_ACP` as the input encoding (i.e. ANSI). If your input string is UTF8 then you can change to use `CP_UTF8` instead.

Once you have a std::wstring you should be able to easily retrieve a SQLWCHAR* using:

```
std::wstring::c_str()
```

Comment: `L` needs one string after it, but in my cas I'm trying to convert one variable.

Comment: Note that on Linux wchar_t is not equal to SQLWCHAR.